# How Do I Change the Style of an Element in a Component When an onClick Event for an Element in a Different Component Occurs?

Tags: reactjs

Basically whenever the Add to Basket button in my Product component is clicked, I want the Shopping Bag in the Header component to flash or expand.

Product Component:

```
import "../styles/Product.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";

function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const addToBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
      item: {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        image: image,
        price: price,
        rating: rating,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product_info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product_price">
          <small>$</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product_rating">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_, i) => (
              <p></p>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
      <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

Header Component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Header.css";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import ShoppingBasketIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingBasket";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";

const Header = () => {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <div className="header">
    
      <div className="header_nav">
               
        <Link to="/checkout">
          <div className="header_optionBasket">
            <ShoppingBasketIcon />
            <span className="header_optionLineTwo header_basketCount">
              {basket?.length}
            </span>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Once the Add to Basket button is clicked, how would we make the shopping bag in the Header component flash or expand?

Would we want to use a state hook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) of React or any other third party state management library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [zustand](https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs/). Otherwise you can simply pass state from a common parent Component down to each Component.

Answer (score 0):

Add useEffect to your cart component to listen to the variable that will be changed, for example basket

Note: this will be in your cart component

```
 // You can use gsap or any other css library here
const tl = gsap.timeline()
const basketDiv = useRef(null)

useEffect(()=>{
tl.from(basketDiv.current,{
1, duration:
 scale: 0.7,
ease: Bounce.easeIn
})
},[basket])

// and whenever the value of basket changes it will run the animation
```

You can check out how to use Gsap with ReactJs.

I hope this is helpful